# Why double quotes are being escaped in JSON.stringify but not single quotes

Tags: json, stringify

I'm creating a json object string that has single quote in the condition which need to be use in sql query. Something like this,`'field IN ('ab'c'd')'` so instead I tried using double quotes for the condition like this `'field IN ("ab'c'd")'` which on doing stringify gives `'field IN (\"ab'c'd\")'`.

Now this messes the whole sql query since the query is trying to execute `SELECT * FROM WHERE field IN (\"ab'c'd\")` instead of `SELECT * FROM WHERE field IN ("ab'c'd")`.

How to work around this?

I tried using `JSON.stringify(s).replace(/\\"/g, '"')` but still looking for any other way. I'have two different db SQL and neo4j so I cant just skip `'` using double `'` I need to write different scenario for escaping the `'` in each db.

Comment: use a prepared statement

Comment: eg. neo4j:https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/

Comment: @jhnc how to use prepare statement in js?

Comment: What you need to do will depend on how you are currently getting your query from javascript to your database server. I'd start by checking the documentation.